# Making two programs work in sync over network

Tags: c, networking, synchronization

I have written three different codes that works on three different machines on a network.

Code 1 on PC1 and Code 2 on PC2 sends 2 different data packets to the Code 3 on PC3(Server).
Code 3 on PC3(Server) takes these packets from PC1 and PC2, XORs them then multicasts it to PC 4,5,6...

The system is working fine but there is a problem; PC3 (Server) needs to take packets from PC1 and PC2 in order. One from PC1 the next is from PC2. Two sequent packets from the same source spoils the system. How can I make Server to take these in order? Most packets are coming in order but every once or twice in a few hundred packets skips the turn and the system gives wrong results. I am working on linux btw using gcc.

Thank you.

Comment: How do you send them over the network? What is the problem with tagging everything with a a sequence number, or using an appropriate protocol that ensures sequencing like TCP?

Comment: You could push the two different packet sets to a queue(you would have to write it) and then take from that queue in the order you want. You may have to write timestamps in the packets to make sure that they are in order.

Comment: How are the packets exchanged? Say if its TCP, can reading alternately from the two sockets do?

Answer (score 0):

A simple boolean flag may be all you need, telling you where the last packet came from.

You start out the program with the flag clear. When you receive a packet from PC1 you set the flag and wait for the next packet. If the next packet is from PC2 and the flag is set, all is well, and you do whatever you want to do, and then clear the flag.

If you receive a packet from PC1 and the flag is *not* clear, then you have a sequence error. If you receive a packet from PC2 and the flag is *not* set, then you have a sequence error too.

---

If you have more than two clients, it might be better to use a simple sequence number. Initialize it to zero, and when you receive from PC1 you set it to one, when you receive from PC2 you set it to two, etc. This way it's easy to see if the next packet received is in sequence.

If you receive a packet out of order, then have a boolean flag that indicates you need to resync. While this flag is set ignore all packets until you receive the next from PC1, when you clear the flag and reset the sequence number to one.

Comment: This looks like the easiest way to go. I am working on virtual machines now and the packets skip every once in every few hundreds. But when I go on physical machines skipping will be much often and maybe more than once, then I have to create a few variables as buffer for each source right?

Comment: @user3541273 Added a more generic solution if you have more than two connected clients.

Comment: This is the other fine idea, I am testing the system on virtual machines now. When I use the physical machines I will control if the sync error happen too often or not. If they don't desync too often then I will go with buffer method if they do I will choose this "using flag to ignore packets until resync" method and go with the synced packets. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would tag every packet with a number. The number would be `x+N*i`, where `x` is the number of PC eg `1` for `PC1`, `N` is the total number of PCs, and `i` is the sequence number of the packet on the PC, that sent it. It's fairly simple modulo mathematics.

*NOTE: You can start numbering PCs from 0, and use `N-1` for the factor.*

This way you can accept packets in random order and decode their proper position in the muxed stream. Thus you can buffer incoming data, and reconstruct the stream on the fly whenever you get the missing packets.

In your case it could be, odd numbers for PC1, and even for PC2.

Comment: This is one fine idea, I am testing the system on virtual machines now. When I use the physical machines I will control if the sync error happen too often or not. If they don't desync too often then I will go with this method if they do I will choose the "using flag to ignore packets until resync" method and go with the synced packets. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To make it really robust PC3 can request packets from PC1 and PC2. PC[1/2] send packets only on request. PC3 requests packet from PC1, waits for it, only then requests packet from PC2, waits for it and then XORs and so on.

Pros: you won't have any sequence errors, everything is controlled

Cons: more code required, result is a bit slower

Comment: This is a really robust idea however I think it would slow the system more than I want. I need to show that this system is faster than the classic unicast.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you expect to process every packet for every machine ? If so, you may need to setup a packet queue for each connection, and then process the queues in order. When you process an empty queue, you just sit down and wait for the next packet to arrive..
If you go for the sequence error solution (with the boolean), a minor delay between two machines will send you in an error status, while peeking the queue will give you tollerance... You should also define a maximum queue size for each connection to avoid growing a queue too much...